# listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: permission denied gin golang

Tags: golang, golang-gin

```go
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    log.Println("started ...")

    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
            "message": "pong",
        })
    })
    r.Run("0.0.0.0:80") 
}
```

Пробовал для дургих портов, всё хорошо работает. Другие компы с локалки заходят.
Почему не даёт запустить на 80 порту и как это сделать?

Comment: Либо порт уже занят, либо нет прав суперпользователя.

Comment: Если у вас линукс, то вашему процессу нужно дать разрешение [CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html)